# React Hooks - update state with new props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm very confused about the new implementations with Hooks.
How can I set State values to the received props, it even not re-rendered when props received.
(which is my desired results)

Here is my code:(I would like to set "amount" value to null unless it received by props, either case it should be in State and to changed).

```
import React from 'react';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default function NumberField(props) {
  const handleAmountChange = (targetValue) => {
    Firebase.database().ref('users/'+Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    +'/details/'+props.date+'/'+props.values.fieldName).set(targetValue);
    setAmount(targetValue);
  }

  const a = props.details[props.values.fieldName];

  const [amount, setAmount] = React.useState(props.details.Calls);

  const GenerateAmount =({amount: a  }) => {
      const  [amount, setAmount] = React.useState(null);
      React.useEffect(() => {
        setAmount (a)
      },{}) 
  }
  return (
    <Box display="flex" p={1} bgcolor={props.values.bgColor}>
    <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="baselline" spacing={2} xs = {12}> 
      <Box display="flex" p={1} >
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Box>
          <Grid container justify="center" > 
            <Button variant="contained" style={buttonStyle} onClick={() => handleAmountChange(props.values.buttons.b1)} >{props.values.buttons.b1}</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" style={buttonStyle}  onClick={() => handleAmountChange(props.values.buttons.b2)} >{props.values.buttons.b2}</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" style={buttonStyle}  onClick={() => handleAmountChange(props.values.buttons.b3)} >{props.values.buttons.b3}</Button>
            </Grid>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Box position="left" left="50%">
          <TextField id="outlined-number" label={props.values.fieldDescription} type="number" value={amount}
            onChange={(e) => handleAmountChange(e.target.value)} 
            InputLabelProps={{shrink: true,}} variant="outlined" />
          </Box>
      </Grid>
        </Box>
    </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you calling useState inside another function? Read the first rule of hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm exactly sure what it is you are asking, but you can use the hook useEffect to listen to when the props change and then set the state.

like this:

```
const [amount, setAdmount] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        setAmount(props.amount);
    }, [props.amount]);
```

Comment: I would make the dependency `props.amount`. `props` will be a new object reference every render so this would be the same as no dependencies.

Comment: Thats true, my mistake. I changed my answer.

Comment: why this is not the accepted answer ? is there something more ?

Comment: Also, I have the feeling the state is not needed here. When state and prop are couple together like this, they are often not needed.

Comment: Thank you ! it works great! (the first value is the value to set to and the second value is the trigger? the value to track? am I correct?)
I need the state to be able to change the value, its a text box. 
when it changes it trigger a function to write it to Firebase DB too.
the useEffect purpose here is to "load" the value and displays it before.

Comment: Hi.Are you asking about the State? If you are, then the first value "amount" is the current state and "setAmount" is a function for updating it.

Comment: If its About the useEffect hook, then ``` [Props.amount] ```, It uses this value to check when its the same between renders, and if it is then the efffect will be skipped. I would recommend reading the docs about it. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html  They also compare it to the previous lifecycle methods if you are more comfortable with those.